# Creating and Inserting new entity from Existing One in Linq To Sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables; PriceList and PriceListDetail with one to many realitonship. After inserting a new PriceList and I need to copy PriceListDetail's of an existing PriceList.

```
var pricedetails= db.PriceListDetails.Where(p => p.PriceList Id == SomeExistingPriceListID);
```

All I need is to change priceListID of pricedetails above and Insert them to PriceListDetail table. When I modify priceListId of pricedetails and try to insert them I get 'cannot insert entities that already exists'.

Obvious solution is to create new entities and copy values one by one from pricedetails then insert.

Is there a way to avoid one by one copying? Maybe create duplicate rows then modify duplicated ones?

Answer (score 1):

Entity frameworks uses another key than your primary key, and it is called an `entity key`.
So having your PriceListDetails, all you have to do is to change the primary key ID and set the entity key to NULL (NULL means a new row).

Comment: I am using linq-to-sql. My classes are generated by dbml and they don't implement IEntityWithKey. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283139%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @Kaplan Hope this link help :http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/94832076-c1af-4f46-a57c-522b1adef498/